# WebSocket cookie

Tags: javascript

Всем привет, коллеги!

У меня не получается установить для вебсокета куку.

На сервере стоит настройка http only, поэтому прямого доступа к авторизационной куке я не имею. Ко всем http запросам я добавляю **withCredentials: true**, чтобы кука, установленная сервером при авторизции, отправлялась обратно при следующих запросах. Это прекрасно работает.

Но у вебсокета нет настройки такого параметра, как withCredentials и кука не подхватывается, соответственно не получается авторизовться.

Есть ли способ передать по вебсокету куку, к которой нет доступа из js?
Если такой возможности нет, то как посоветуете организовать авторизацию в такой ситуации?

**UPD**

Такая картина наблюдаетя только при кроссдоменных подключениях. Когда клиент и сервер на одном хосте, то всё нормально.

Comment: Я думаю, что нужны уточнения: 1) куда у Вас есть доступ 2) Как Вы определяете, что кука не подхватывается?

Comment: @Дмытрык, 1) весь клиент написан мною, так что в любую его часть. 2) подключение к вебсокету происходит в 2 этапа. Сначала посылается гет запрос с хеадером upgrade и если сервер развешает обновиться, то соединение обновляется до вебсокетного (101 код). Это происходит в случае удачной авторизации. Если авторизация не удалась, то в консоли разработчика остается только первый запрос. Там видны все заголовки запроса и ответа